# How can I install hundreds of pkg files?

Tags: pkg

I have a directory full of pkg files that I need to install.  I tried "installer -packages *.pkg" , but that didn't work.  Any ideas on how to do this?  Do I need to make a metapackage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use cycle for this. You can type next in your terminal command line:

```
for f in *.pkg; do installer -packages "$f"; done
```

Comment: Quote the variable: `installer -packages "$f"` will help avoid things failing or possibly going horribly awry should any of the package files have spaces in their names.

Comment: @thrig right, thanx!